# parallel arrays and structs? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, parallel-processing

Okay here are my variables i am trying to put into one struct, i am a little worried on how i should implement a parallel array using the struct.  Is the struct "studentType" correct?

```
const int NUM_STUDENTS = 10; //global variables
const int NUM_SCORES = 5;


string studentNames[NUM_STUDENTS], letterGrades[NUM_STUDENTS]; //old program variables
float studentAverages[NUM_STUDENTS];
int studentScores[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_SCORES];

struct studentType{ 
    string name;
    string grade;
    float average;
    int scores[NUM_SCORES];
};
studentType student[NUM_STUDENTS];
```

i appreciate all the help in advance!

Comment: what do you mean with "parallel array"?

Comment: parallel array as in studentScores[NUM_STUDENTS][NUM_SCORES]; how do i implement that into a struct? making it an array in the struct then declaring a variable of the struct as an array?

Comment: By "parallel" you mean "multidimensional"? Does your approach not work correctly?

Comment: no here is my code and errors http://pastebin.com/GzPTb76h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You declared the structure as global. So you don't need to pass it
  always. Just keep length of array
- You better to use classes.

I had fixed the compilation errors. (not logical errors)

http://pastebin.com/zWDtXtHZ